Comma before "and"
I am confused.
Looking at Cambridge dict. and even "British Council", there it says:
for Example - "She has a sister, a dog and two brothers" without a comma before "and", but I learned during international business study some years ago to use a "comma" before "and".  Also some of my students and some teachers are confused.  Can we solve this ?  Kind Regards, Frank

There is a rule stating that we have to use comma before coordinating conjunction when it connects independent clauses. But my answer received a downvote even though I gave a link. I had also seen commas being used when it connects nouns. But it is optional.

Oxford comma

So what to recommend to "German A1-A2 school students ? And also to global learners, who are not working at NewYork Times ?


For everyday communication, do whatever makes you happiest. Although many people joke about having strong feelings about it—or maybe aren't really joking!—using the Oxford Comma is a matter of style and is not "right or wrong," so no one can fault you for choosing either way. Though those who want it seem to be "louder" than those who don't, so that might be a reason to use it. 2) When writing an academic paper for a teacher, ask what they prefer, or check whether the school has its own style guide and follow that. Same for writing for money for a company.


For sure,  I agree and advised my students to handle it like you said.  I thought, maybe there is a "clear" academically guideline, somewhere and sometime.

Can we solve this ? ... solve what?

jsotala, the confusion :-)

This is the famous Oxford Comma. It is optional, and different style guides have different opinions on whether it should be used or not. The Oxford Style Manual recommends that it be used (hence the name), but many others (AP, NYT) recommend not using it. It is up to you.

Note: The Oxford Comma relates specifically to lists of three or more things. This is what is going on in the example sentence you provided: "a sister, a dog[,] and two brothers." The word and has many uses outside of lists, and in these cases there are different rules. For eample:

As @James_Mathai points out, a comma is required when and is being used to connect two independent clauses.
If you are talking a pair of things, then it is incorrect to put a comma between them: "horse and cart" instead of "horse, and cart"


In the USA we would not usually put a comma there, whether a rule says we should or not.  It is so uncommon to see a comma before the and that I wouldn't put one there in a business letter because someone might think it doesn't belong there.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
